# Apache Airflow broken migration prevents from running standalone mode

Tags: python, airflow

I've installed Apache Airflow locally, using Pip, and run in standalone mode like instructed in the [Docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/local.html).

###### The problem

After the restart, trying to run again `airflow standalone`, gives me this error:

```
standalone | Starting Airflow Standalone
standalone | Checking database is initialized
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 127d2bf2dfa7 -> cc1e65623dc7, add max tries column to task instance
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: duplicate column name: max_tries

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 40, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/standalone_command.py", line 48, in entrypoint
    StandaloneCommand().run()
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/standalone_command.py", line 64, in run
    self.initialize_database()
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/standalone_command.py", line 170, in initialize_database
    db.initdb()
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 591, in initdb
    upgradedb(session=session)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 67, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 824, in upgradedb
    command.upgrade(config, 'heads')
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 298, in upgrade
    script.run_env()
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 489, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 98, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/util/compat.py", line 184, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 107, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 101, in run_migrations_online
    context.run_migrations()
  File "<string>", line 8, in run_migrations
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/runtime/environment.py", line 846, in run_migrations
    self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 518, in run_migrations
    step.migration_fn(**kw)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/migrations/versions/cc1e65623dc7_add_max_tries_column_to_task_instance.py", line 60, in upgrade
    op.add_column('task_instance', sa.Column('max_tries', sa.Integer, server_default="-1"))
  File "<string>", line 8, in add_column
  File "<string>", line 3, in add_column
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/operations/ops.py", line 1927, in add_column
    return operations.invoke(op)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/operations/base.py", line 374, in invoke
    return fn(self, operation)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/operations/toimpl.py", line 132, in add_column
    operations.impl.add_column(table_name, column, schema=schema, **kw)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/ddl/impl.py", line 237, in add_column
    self._exec(base.AddColumn(table_name, column, schema=schema))
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/ddl/impl.py", line 140, in _exec
    return conn.execute(construct, *multiparams, **params)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1011, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 72, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_ddl(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1068, in _execute_ddl
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1316, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1510, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) duplicate column name: max_tries
[SQL: ALTER TABLE task_instance ADD COLUMN max_tries INTEGER DEFAULT '-1']
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

When trying to reset database using `airflow db reset`, it returns this:

```
airflow db reset
DB: sqlite:////root/airflow/airflow.db
This will drop existing tables if they exist. Proceed? (y/n)y
[2021-10-18 15:17:43,572] {db.py:831} INFO - Dropping tables that exist
[2021-10-18 15:17:43,704] {migration.py:154} INFO - Context impl SQLiteImpl.
[2021-10-18 15:17:43,705] {migration.py:157} INFO - Will assume non-transactional DDL.
[2021-10-18 15:17:43,800] {db.py:823} INFO - Creating tables
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade  -> e3a246e0dc1, current schema
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade e3a246e0dc1 -> 1507a7289a2f, create is_encrypted
/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/ddl/sqlite.py:40 UserWarning: Skipping unsupported ALTER for creation of implicit constraintPlease refer to the batch mode feature which allows for SQLite migrations using a copy-and-move strategy.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 1507a7289a2f -> 13eb55f81627, maintain history for compatibility with earlier migrations
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 13eb55f81627 -> 338e90f54d61, More logging into task_instance
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 338e90f54d61 -> 52d714495f0, job_id indices
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 52d714495f0 -> 502898887f84, Adding extra to Log
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 502898887f84 -> 1b38cef5b76e, add dagrun
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 1b38cef5b76e -> 2e541a1dcfed, task_duration
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 2e541a1dcfed -> 40e67319e3a9, dagrun_config
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 40e67319e3a9 -> 561833c1c74b, add password column to user
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 561833c1c74b -> 4446e08588, dagrun start end
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 4446e08588 -> bbc73705a13e, Add notification_sent column to sla_miss
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade bbc73705a13e -> bba5a7cfc896, Add a column to track the encryption state of the 'Extra' field in connection
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade bba5a7cfc896 -> 1968acfc09e3, add is_encrypted column to variable table
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 1968acfc09e3 -> 2e82aab8ef20, rename user table
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 2e82aab8ef20 -> 211e584da130, add TI state index
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 211e584da130 -> 64de9cddf6c9, add task fails journal table
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 64de9cddf6c9 -> f2ca10b85618, add dag_stats table
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade f2ca10b85618 -> 4addfa1236f1, Add fractional seconds to mysql tables
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 4addfa1236f1 -> 8504051e801b, xcom dag task indices
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 8504051e801b -> 5e7d17757c7a, add pid field to TaskInstance
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 5e7d17757c7a -> 127d2bf2dfa7, Add dag_id/state index on dag_run table
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 127d2bf2dfa7 -> cc1e65623dc7, add max tries column to task instance
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 40, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/db_command.py", line 39, in resetdb
    db.resetdb()
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 839, in resetdb
    initdb(session=session)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 67, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 591, in initdb
    upgradedb(session=session)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 67, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 824, in upgradedb
    command.upgrade(config, 'heads')
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 298, in upgrade
    script.run_env()
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 489, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 98, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/util/compat.py", line 184, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 107, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 101, in run_migrations_online
    context.run_migrations()
  File "<string>", line 8, in run_migrations
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/runtime/environment.py", line 846, in run_migrations
    self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 540, in run_migrations
    raise util.CommandError(
alembic.util.exc.CommandError: Migration "upgrade 127d2bf2dfa7 -> cc1e65623dc7, add max tries column to task instance" has left an uncommitted transaction opened; transactional_ddl is False so Alembic is not committing transactions
```

Command `airflow db check-migrations` returns this:

```
[2021-10-18 15:19:12,201] {migration.py:154} INFO - Context impl SQLiteImpl.
[2021-10-18 15:19:12,201] {migration.py:157} INFO - Will assume non-transactional DDL.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 40, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/db_command.py", line 54, in check_migrations
    db.check_migrations(timeout=args.migration_wait_timeout)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/localspark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 643, in check_migrations
    raise TimeoutError(
TimeoutError: There are still unapplied migrations after 0 seconds. Migration Head(s) in DB: {'127d2bf2dfa7'} | Migration Head(s) in Source Code: {'7b2661a43ba3'}
```

###### Fixes tried

Deleting the Airflow DB (even the whole Airflow home directory) doesn't help. Uninstalling and reinstalling Airflow either

###### The question

Is there a way to either fix these broken migrations or remove the Airflow in a way that would also get rid of this problem?